# Need network segmentation, like Multi-Tenant Unit VLAN, on a D-Link smart switch

Tags: networking, router, security, home-networking, vlan

For better security of working from home, I need to separate network traffics into different groups so that:

- These groups all have access to the Internet, e.g. for work, personal, home appliances, surveillance cameras, etc.; but
- the different groups cannot reach each other
- Need cable connections on all the groups for better transmission speed, so the guest WIFI is not fast enough. Also, the guest WIFI only divides the network into groups of main and guest, while we need three or more.

I heard [MTU VLAN (Multi-Tenant Unit VLAN)](https://stevessmarthomeguide.com/vlans-home-networks/) uses a shared uplink port connected to the Internet. And the other ports can send and receive data on the uplink port, but not between each other. And I saw the terminology "MTU VLAN" in the user manual of TP-Link.

I have a [D-Link DGS-1100-08V2](https://support.dlink.com/resource/PRODUCTS/DGS-1100-SERIES/DGS-1100-05_05PD_08_08P_REVB_MANUAL_v2.21_WW_EN.pdf), and it's a layer-2 smart managed switch, but I didn't find direct support of MTU VLAN.

**My Questions:**

- I wonder if there is a way to set up traffic segmentation with Internet access? E.g. by using the security features of traffic segmentation, and putting together some port forwarding rules, etc.?
- Please remind me if I missed something about this hardware; for example, not sure if there is an equivalent feature to MTU VLAN.
- Or, after all, is it feasible to use traffic segmentation in home networking?

I do see a lot of discussions about this demand, though. And people seem to prefer a one-stop solution including router, switch, and WIFI in the same piece of hardware.

I am unfamiliar with networking and don't understand many of the terminologies listed in the text block below. So I highly appreciate any suggestions, links, videos, tutorials, etc.

**More Details:**

- The router is an integrated modem from the Internet service provider, and it has WiFi and DHCP with reservation functionality on subnet `192.168.x.xxx/24`. Just if interesting to you.
- List of the switch's functionalities:

```
Model DGS-1100-08V2:
System
    System Information Settings
    System Information
        IPv4 Interface
        Port Configuration
    Port Configuration

Management
    Password Access Control
    SNMP
        SNMP Global Settings
        SNMP Community Table Settings
        SNMP Host Settings
    D-Link Discovery Protocol

L2 Features
    FDB
        Static FDB
            Unicast Static FDB
            Multicast Static FDB
        MAC Address Table Settings
        MAC Address Table

    VLAN
        802.1Q VLAN
        Port-Based VLAN
        Management VLAN
        Asymmetric VLAN
        Surveillance VLAN
        Voice VLAN

    Spanning Tree
        STP Global Settings
        STP Port Settings

    Loopback Detection
    Link Aggregation

    L2 Multicast Control
        IGMP Snooping
            IGMP Snooping Settings
            IGMP Snooping Groups Settings

QoS
    802.1p/DSCP Default Priority
    Port Rate Limiting

Security
    Traffic Segmentation
    Storm Control
    Port Security

OAM
    Cable Diagnostics

Monitoring
    Statistics
    Port Counters
    Mirroring Settings

Green
    EEE
```

- [Screenshot of the switch's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U30eN.png) (Not sure if my username has enough points to upload this picture, if not, please refer to the text block above.)

Comment: Never heard of this “MTU VLAN”. You want port-based for regular devices and tagged to the upstream router, which has to support it.

Comment: Oh, MTU VLAN here stands for "Multi-Tenant Unit VLAN". I saw the word in manuals of TP-Link, just that I have a D-Link switch now and still hope to use it.

Comment: It appears to be a proprietary TP-LINK feature. It cannot be realized using only VLANs. It probably is full of holes, too. If you want isolation, you need a VLAN-capable router.

Comment: Thank you for your pointers, @DanielB. Could you please give a few examples of VLAN-capable routers for home use? Or some keywords that I can search?

Comment: Mikrotik has plenty of (comparatively) cheap routers that would do. How you feel about Mikrotik, with WinBox and whatnot, is up to you! All the usual router makers probably also have some “premium SOHO” product lines that you could investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And the other ports can send and receive data on the uplink port, but not between each other

This feature is more commonly called "**port isolation**" or "**private VLAN**". (Sometimes even "client isolation", which is a Wi-Fi term for the same thing.)

It *might* be found under "asymmetric VLAN" in your screenshot, or it *might* be lumped together with port-based or 802.1Q-based VLANs in some switches (technically it has nothing to do with the 802.1Q VLAN feature, but they do often get used in combination).

---

That being said, what you're trying to achieve is more commonly done in a different way – using 802.1Q VLANs, which give a somewhat different result: instead of ports being individually isolated but all sharing a single subnet, each *group* of ports (i.e. each VLAN ID) is isolated into a fully separate subnet (e.g. "work" VLAN 2 is 192.168.2.0/24 while "device" VLAN 3 is 192.168.3.0/24). Note that 802.1Q VLANs do not prevent devices within the same VLAN from communicating directly, but they can still be combined with port isolation if needed.

However, this would also require the *router* to support 802.1Q VLANs (as it needs to manage multiple virtual LAN interfaces, one for each VLAN ID), and yours probably doesn't.